# Do trade routes activate between my cities when a road goes through city states or other civilizations' cities?

Tags: civilization-5

Suppose I've got a capital, a city, and a city state in between, where the dashes represent roads:

Capital ------ City-State ----- My City

The road goes straight through the city-state.  I understand that I don't get a trade route to the city-state, but would I still get a trade route to my city?  Or would I have to build around the city-state?  And do the same rules apply if the city-state was replaced with another civ's city?

Inspired by [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9844/do-i-gain-income-for-connecting-city-states-to-my-trade-network).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Regarding passing through another civ or city-states territory:

Trade routes can pass through other civs as long as you have open borders agreement from them. Trade routes do not work through a civ you're in war with, even though technically your units can pass within their borders.

Regarding city-states, it works of you are either friends or allied with them.

### Regarding passing through an actual city:

I believe it's precisely the same as the above - your road passing through the actual city shouldn't make a difference, except for saving you money, since cities count as road tiles.

Comment: I can verify this, trade routes work through other civs as long as you have open borders (but not at war) and work through city states as long as you are friendly with them.